# Redis python: scan() function returns nothing. but dbsize returns value bigger than zero

Tags: python, database, redis

I use Redis-py to communicate with Redis database in python using the following code.

Some while when I get list of the database keys using the function keys(n).

But when I get the size of database using dbsize() function I get the number bigger than Zero.
It just happens in some specific times and I have no idea why it happens.
Do you have any idea why?

There is the code I wrote:

```py
REDIS_SERVER = redis.Redis(
    host=REDIS_HOST,
    port=REDIS_PORT,
    db=REDIS_DB,
    decode_responses=True
)
n=5
keys = REDIS_SERVER.scan(count=n)[1]
db_size = REDIS_SERVER.dbsize()
```

My purpose is to get specific number of keys from database. I prefer not to use keys() function because of performance issues. Is there any other way instead of using scan() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SCAN` is meant to be used iteratively in a loop; you start by requestinflg cursor zero, and with the page of results (which may be empty) it gives you back the *next* cursor to use - which you give it back over and over until it hands you back the sentinel zero.

The other number you give it is not an"give me this many results per page" - as that might necessitate large waits for filtered results. Instead it is more of a "do this much work" hint - no matter what you pass in, in can still return you zero results. Imagine a large database and you're using the filtered version of`SCAN` and the only match turns out the be the last thing it finds in the database; to avoid blocking other work, all of the many many "nothing here, try back with this token" results still need to complete quickly, and not block until it has scanned everything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marc. I try this and use scan in loop, each time with the previous scan cursor. But most of the time I get desired number of keys in the first scan although the returned cursor isn't 0. should I call scan again in these cases too? I think I should check the scan result length and try again only if I don't get the desired keys. Is this right?

Comment: @Mehdi343 if you get enough in your first call, then fine: stop asking. If you only want 20, and you have 20 or more - great, stop! But if you want 20 and get fewer than that and have not seen zero returned, then yes you should probably keep asking